# Grid seems not to work with react-images-upload

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

So I am using react-images-uploading ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-uploading ) package and I want to display the previews with a "dynamic" grid, by transforming the index into a char and setting different grid-templates depending on the size of the imagesList. This is the code I'm running:

**component.js**

```js
const getGridStyles = (imageList) => {
    const numImages = imageList.length;
    let gridStyles = {
      gridTemplateAreas: "'A'",
    };

    if (numImages === 2) {
      gridStyles.gridTemplateAreas = "'A B'";
    } else if (numImages === 3) {
      gridStyles.gridTemplateAreas = "'A A' 'B C'";
    } else if (numImages === 4) {
      gridStyles.gridTemplateAreas = "'A B' 'C D'";
    } else if (numImages >= 5) {
      gridStyles.gridTemplateAreas = "'A B' 'C D' 'E E'";
    }
    console.log(gridStyles);
    return gridStyles;
  };

<ImageUploading
                  multiple
                  value={images}
                  onChange={onImagesChange}
                  //   maxNumber={maxNumber}
                  dataURLKey="data_url"
                  acceptType={['jpg']}
                >
                  {({
                    imageList,
                    onImageUpload,
                    onImageRemoveAll,
                    onImageUpdate,
                    onImageRemove,
                    isDragging,
                    dragProps,
                  }) => (
                    <div className="upload__image-wrapper">
                      <button
                        style={isDragging ? { color: 'red' } : null}
                        onClick={onImageUpload}
                        {...dragProps}
                      >
                        Click or Drop here
                      </button>
                      &nbsp;
                      <button onClick={onImageRemoveAll}>
                        Remove all images
                      </button>
                      <div
                        className="image-gallery"
                        style={getGridStyles(imageList)}
                      >
                        {imageList.slice(0, 5).map((image, index) => (
                          <div
                            key={index}
                            className={`image-item ${
                              imageList.length > 5 && index === 4
                                ? 'more-photos'
                                : ''
                            }`}
                          >
                            <div
                              className="image-block"
                              style={{
                                backgroundImage: `url(${image.data_url})`,
                                minHeight: '200px',
                                maxHeight: '400px',
                                gridArea: String.fromCharCode(index + 65),
                              }}
                            >
                              {' '}
                            </div>

                            <div className="image-item__btn-wrapper">
                              <button onClick={() => onImageUpdate(index)}>
                                Update
                              </button>
                              <button onClick={() => onImageRemove(index)}>
                                Remove
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                        {imageList.length > 5 && (
                          <div className="more-photos">
                            +{imageList.length - 5} more photos
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </ImageUploading>
```

**style.css**

```css
.image-block {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

or check stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstraap-qrgy2l?file=app.css

However, the grid layout does not seem to work, as when I'm uploading three photos, instead of the 'A A' 'B C' I get more of a 'A B' 'C' meaning that the 3 photos take 50% width each, instead of the first taking 100% and then the rest taking 50% each.

What am I doing wrong? As a reference, this is the layout I want to achieve when there's three photos:
https://codepen.io/vwjvvsoy-the-bashful/pen/gOZzwzb